# Finding and matching two strings in different arrays

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

I'm trying to pass two arguments into a script that looks through arrays with a lot of values.

Basically, I have a pretty big JSON file with around 15 arrays (google sheet data). I then want to take the 1st argument, which is one/multiple words and match it in the 1st array. And then I want to take index numbers in the 1st array and only look through those index numbers in the 2nd array for a string that matches the 2nd argument and return the strings and the index number for future use. For example:

```
sheetData = [ [ "1stArray", "other", "other"  ], [ "2ndArray", "stuff", "2stuff", "stuff" "2stuff" ] ]
```

If I then would type in: node index.js other 2stuff. It is supposed to find the two "other" entries in the 1st array, then look at the "stuff" and the first "2stuff" in the 2nd array and then return both "2stuff" and the index number 2.

So far I've been able to find one of the strings matching the 1st argument in the 1st array, but not the other ones. Nor have I been able to even go through the 2nd array trying to find another string. Here is the code I've written so far for this:

```
let fs = {
help: config.help.failstack,
func: (client, message, args) => {
    // E = Enhance, R = Repair/replace, D = re-enhance (degrade part),
    let itemName = args[0];
    let enhanceWanted = args[1];

    debugger;
    var a = sheetData.values[[0]];
    var sheetItemName = a.indexOf(itemName);
    if (sheetItemName === -1) {

        message.reply('Command not formatted correctly.')
            .then(msg => console.log())
            .catch(console.error);
    } else {

        var sheetFailstack = a.indexOf(enhanceWanted);
        message.reply()
            .then(msg => console.log(`${msg}`))
            .catch(console.error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var sheetFailstack = a.indexOf[enhanceWanted];
```

should be:

```
 var sheetFailstack = a.indexOf(enhanceWanted);
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it!

Comment: Didn't answer the question but it did fix a formatting error.

Comment: what is the issue you facing. You should be able to find another string.

Comment: I have no idea how to write the code I want, and I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Comment: why this: var a = sheetData.values[[0]]; it should be var a = sheetData.[0];

Comment: All the arrays are inside another array.